# jquery image map hover effects

Tags: jquery, html, maps

I have created an image map and i want to highlight maps areas on mouse over. To achieve this i wrote following code.

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#Map area').hover(function(){
                alert('alert');
                $(this).css('border','1px solid #FF0000');
            });
        });
</script>
```

html:

```
<div id="mainmap"><img src="images/map.jpg" alt="" usemap="#Map"/></div>
<map name="Map" id="Map">
        <area shape="poly" coords="21,326,203,316,220,141,52,153,48,182,37,193,29,220,27,241,28,255,33,259" href="#" alt="1" />
        <area shape="poly" coords="31,405,209,410,225,427,336,427,337,360,200,359,208,317,21,326,15,344,41,360" href="#" alt="11" />
</map>
```

When i mouse over an area it alerts twice while i think it is supposed to alert once. Also **.css()** function does not seem to work with **this** selector.

Please guide how can i fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand what `<map>` means, it's a simple definition on the click areas of an image

saying `$(this).css('border','1px solid #FF0000');` you are telling to make the `<map>` have a solid border, but `<map>` is just like the `<head>` elements, it only contains definitions.

To make the borders in the areas, you really need to have 2 images instead.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when you move mouse in the map area, an alert will pop out, at this point, your mouse is out of the map area, so the `onmouseleave` event was triggered, so there are two `alerts`. if you replace them with `console.log`, it should be fine. Test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/8ZXb9/